# checkbox implementation on angular 4.4

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I got this angular snippet for a select box and it works. 
How do I turn this to a checkbox?

```
<mat-form-field class="example-medium-width">
   <mat-select matInput name="learnerType" [(ngModel)]="learningPlan.learnerTypes" placeholder="Learner Type" multiple #field_learnerType="ngModel">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let learnerType of learnerTypes" [value]="learnerType">
        {{ learnerType }}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The examples on checkboxes on material.angular.io website, are about checkboxes where each having different names! Typically, you'd want the related checkbox options to tie to the name. Only then, you can send the checked values to the server as one big piece ( with comma sep. ).

Just like the above select UI options. 
But I want the options to be laid out as checkbox.

part 2 // this is after trying the example at the material.angular.io

The below also does not work. I attached the error message after the code snippet.

```
<mat-form-field matInput class="example-medium-width">
    <section class="example-section">
        <mat-checkbox matInput name="checked" class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checked">Checked</mat-checkbox>
        <mat-checkbox matInput name="indeterminate" class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="indeterminate">Indeterminate</mat-checkbox>
    </section>
</mat-form-field>
```

Error this code generates is the following:

`ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. Did you forget to add matInput to the native input or textarea element?
    at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError (form-field.es5.js:89)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add controls to FormArray and get the checked value based on the selection

```
<div *ngFor="let cricketer of cricketers; let i = index" >
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" 
    (change)="onChange($event)" [value]="cricketer">{{cricketer}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

**[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7jput?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you for the example. It works. But that's reactive solution. Can this be solved for Template Driven forms? I'm just adding the part2 into my original question as to demonstrate what also does not work.

Comment: @AverageJoe At the moment, it's not possible to put a `<mat-checkbox>` in a `<mat-form-field>`. There's an issue on Github here: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7891